# Separate logs for multiple instances of the same process?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have a java console application that can be run simultaneously by multiple users, but I need separate log for each of these java processes. It would be run on the same machine... I'm using slf4j with log4j.

Is this possible in any way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See this link on how to setup multiple log files:

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1311014

I think something like this should work, since user names are unique:

If you just want one log for each user, you could just make different logs for different user names in your configuration file automatically when a user first opens your application (say, `User1Log`,`User2Log`... et cetera), and then use some code like this to specify which log to use from within your application:

`Logger logger= Logger.getLogger(System.getProperty("user.name") + "Log");`

So, someone logged in under `User1` will have a log tied to `User1Log` in your configuration file.